# Is it okay to quote old performance reviews on my resume?

Tags: resume, performance-reviews

I've been coached to include a list of 'strengths' on my resume, in addition to my past experience and technical qualifications. I don't understand how me writing that I'm a detail-oriented team player and a fast learner is going to tell a recruiter anything other than the fact that I'm good at BS'ing buzz words.

However, I have a cache of previous glowing performance reviews that touch on all of the strengths I would want to highlight, and they are quotes straight from my current and previous supervisors. Is there anything wrong with listing some quotes from these performance reviews on my resume as strengths? And how valuable is it to list strengths on a resume, anyway?

Answer (score 3):

> I've been coached to include a list of 'strengths' on my resume... I don't understand how me writing that I'm a detail-oriented team player and a fast learner is going to tell a recruiter anything other than the fact that I'm good at BS'ing buzz words.

**Fire your coach**

You are already much more knowledgeable than your coach.  You understand adding stuff like "team player" and "detail-oriented" are more likely to get you an eye-roll than a job.

Take a look at Ask A Manager's [how to write a resume that doesn’t suck](https://www.askamanager.org/2018/06/how-to-write-a-resume-that-doesnt-suck.html).

Here is an excerpt from the link discussing skills section (emphasis mine)

> If you do include a Skills section, **limit it to hard skills, like
> software programs and foreign languages you’re fluent in. Don’t list
> subjective self-assessments like “strong written communication skills”
> or “visionary leader” or “works well independently and in groups.”**
> People’s self-assessments are so often wildly inaccurate that these
> won’t carry any weight with employers and just take up space that
> would be better spent on something more compelling.

Comment: That article is terrible advice.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter - why is it terrible?

Comment: First off, she's going by the old "one or two page" standard of resumes.  That went out in the 1990s.  It's also bland, unsophisticated and filled with "maybe you do, maybe you don't" nonsense.  You could get better advice from peeking at a colleague's resume

Answer (score 1):

This will REALLY depend on your industry.  If you are going for a management consultant role including the buzzwords used correctly would be a demonstration of the skillset.  If you are going for a carpentry job it will get your resume thrown into the round file.

As a rough guide, I think the more corporate the role and the higher the role is in the organization the more value you get from demonstrating you are able to use the corporate buzz wordy vernacular.

Comment: This makes sense. I am applying for mostly management type roles. What are your thoughts on using performance review quotes?

Comment: Upvoted, but I disagree with the use of buzzwords, ever.   I've never seen anyone benefit from their use.  We even used to print out cards like these to bring to meetings.  (and yes, I was management)  https://www.buzzwordbingogame.com/cards/buzzword/

Comment: @StrangerHopeful I would look at the specifics of the job posting and tailor your resume to fit it.  If you have performance review quotes that directly support language used in the posting I would include them.  If you don't have anything that directly fits, don't try to force it.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter I have the same general feeling towards buzz words. That bingo game is amazing.

Comment: @StrangerHopeful LOL, I've been playing for 20 years now.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a resume is to get you an interview.

Performance reviews are designed to be laden with weasel word laden nonsense, never quote them, it won't look good.

You do want to list your strengths in an effective way.

I used to teach a class on writing Resumes, so hear goes with some rules that can apply in most cases:

Stating up front here, these vary from industry to industry, and company to company.  You are going to want to tweak your resume to fit both the industry and company.  Doing so will also prepare you for the interview question "What do you know about our company?"

And now, for the rules:

**- SHOW, DON'T Tell**

What looks better on a resume, "I'm very detail oriented", or "Corrected a flaw in the widget system, saving company 200,000 in lost revenue"?

**- QUANTIFY WHAT YOU DID**

Again, what sounds better "Increased efficiency leading to higher performance.", or "Automated widget reordering process, reducing labor cost by 10%, and increased productivity by freeing staff to do more complex tasks"?

**- C.A.R. Challenge, Action Result**

(or at least action-result) Your bullet items should directly demonstrate something you did that is of tangible value (see above) Resume's are boring, any resume that is not, will get the reader's attention.

If I see something like "I proactively engineered a paradigm shift to create a new synergy helping to monetize reserve resources....."   YAWN.  Your resume is going to go into the bin.

However:  "Streamlined development process through use of (tool/tech) resulting project being completed early, saving X weeks and X dollars for XYX company", NOW you've got my attention.

You want your resume to paint an interesting picture which is going to get you an invitation to an interview where they will want to know more.

To put on my marketing hat here for a minute:

You want your resume to be a VERB, not a noun.  (metaphorically speaking).

Here's a final example of what I mean:

Instead of "I'm a good listener", how about something like "Found out through discussions with client that client did not have rights to expand operations in the city he had chosen.  Called for cancellation of project, saving client 5 million in unnecessary costs"

**TLDR  Your resume should contain ZERO buzzwords, and should be all about your skills and achievements with abundant, tangible examples.

Comment: What's the best way to show less quantifiable achievements, like winning over clients and stakeholders, or having a reputation for delivering quality products? I have no tangible record of saving the company xx dollars or improving efficiency by xx%.

Comment: @StrangerHopeful  Those are still tangible.  "Achieved a solid reputation among customers and stakeholders by repeated delivery of high-quality products."  or "Established record of successful negotiation with key stakeholders."  Include HOW you won them over, if possible.

Comment: And if I have a direct quote from my supervisor saying something very similar to this, would it be worthwhile to put that on my resume?

Comment: @StrangerHopeful Yes, but save the attribution to the interview, specifically, if they ask the old "Why should we hire you", you can **honestly** respond.  "I have excellent skills in dealing with customers and stakeholders, in fact, my last manager even noted that in my annual review".